# Web, SQL: display random images despite file name, load images from folder

Tags: php, sql, css, image, random

I want a web page to display several random images on load. I've thought of several solutions but I would really like to be able to dump images into a folder without renaming them, and the web page will choose from those images in the folder and display them

I can imagine a PHP solution that will display random images from a folder, but it will need to look for certain names.

So my next step was to have an SQL database where every image got a key, and 10 keys would be chosen random by a query - the images associated with them would then be passed into an array that the document will load the elements of.

But now I guess I need to know how to automatically populate an SQL database by having it read a folder?

Insight appreciated, if I don't have to reinvent the wheel the better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glob works like on the filesystem, e.g. supports wildcards

```
$files = glob('/path/to/files/*.jpg');
$yourRandomFile = array_rand($files);
```

This will return a random JPG file, based on it's extension.

Comment: ah this is the right track, is there a javascript version of this function as well?

Comment: Not really, in javascript you wouldn't know what files are on the server. You would have to load all filenames from the server, write them to a javascript array and use `Math.random()`..

Comment: Yeah I just went with the php function with a giant echo statement for the existing HTML page

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
function your_dir ($directory) 

{

$results = array();

$handler = opendir($directory);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) {

  if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

    $results[] = $file;

    //or sql query for each file

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_file = '".$file."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows !== 0){

    //your query...

    }

    //

  }


}

closedir($handler);

return $results;

}


$directory = '/path/to/your/directory';

your_dir($directory);
```

Would probably be better to select existing files from db first put them into an array and exclude them rather than checking for each one.

Comment: I should follow this SQL route because the images need a thumbnail to correspond to

Comment: You could use this loop to create thumbnails at the same time, it all depends on how many files you have/will have in your folder

Comment: The approach that I implemented instead used PHP only. I used the glob function to get the files listing in an array, then I shuffled the array and took a splice of it. Whenever I called the image I could also call it's corresponding thumbnail file because it follows a naming convention. I made an additional function to replace a substring and return that new string as the thumbnail file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below.
1. read complete dir from where you want the page to load the image
2. store the image names in array
3. now generate a number using random function from 1 to size of the array
4. consider the generated number as key for the array and use that image name to put the image.